# java.util.NoSuchElementException occuring while performing operation on arraylist

Tags: java

I want to filter the first list based on some string match from second list.

```
  private void getFilteredList(List<String> fileLst, List<OrderDetailsDTO> msisdnList) {
    Iterator<String> it = fileLst.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
      for(OrderDetailsDTO item: msisdnList){
        if(it.next() != null && ! it.next().contains(item.getMsisdn())){
          it.remove();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, a [mcve], and a clear description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it.next() twice. Once you have performed it.hasNext() you can directly perform it.next().contains(item.getMsisdn()) instead of checking it.next() != null.

it.next()

Returns:
the next element in the iteration

Throws:
NoSuchElementException - if the iteration has no more elements

So you should always call it.hasNext() before calling it.next();

Please check 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--